# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ini4j/InvalidFileFormatException by gradle

Tags: java, gradle, executable-jar, manifest.mf, ini4j

When I want to run jar from my gradle project it shows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ini4j/InvalidFileFormatException
```

My build.gradle in short:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'pmd'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

version = "0.0.0"
group= "grm"

mainClassName = 'grm.bol.Launcher'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.ini4j', name: 'ini4j', version: 'latest.release'
}

jar {
    manifest {
    attributes "Main-Class": "grm.bol.Launcher"
    attributes "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
    }
}
```

When I run in eclipse ini4j works fine without any worning. Also build gradle task is successfully.
But I cannot run it even if generated manifest.mf looks like that:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: grm.bol.Launcher
Class-Path: ini4j-0.5.2.jar
```

Somebody know the reason what is happening with manifest?

Comment: That Class-Path entry mandates that the ini4j Jar sits next to the Jar that you are building. Did you make sure of that, by copying it there? For an easier out-of-the-box experience, consider using the `application` plugin.

Comment: I want to make only one jar. So in lib folder is only that jar file which I want to run

Comment: As I said, the Class-Path entry that you declared requires an ini4j Jar in the same directory as your Jar. The entry shouldn't be required for running the app with the application plugin's `run` task.

Comment: Copying ini4j file into lib folder worked.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably when you try to run it you mess something with classpath so wrong version of InvalidFileFormatException is used. If you have fat jar it may be version conflict at build time.